# android studio gradle sync fail

Tags: android, gradle, adb

showing "Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc000007b" in the log terminal.
all SDKs are updated. ive installed microsoft visual c++ latest. set the variable path of the android platform tools adb.exe.
cmd window shows error message.

Comment: Can you please add the log details in question.

Comment: Hi...I've tried everything available on the net but it seems like ultimately i will have to upgrade or formate my pc...in which case  i formated and installed windows10 os . Android Studio was installed smoothly and seems to be working fine .anyways thanks